# Is is possible to point a subdirectory of a website do a domain?

Tags: web, cross-domain

Is is possible to point a subdirectory of a website to another domain. Example our site is http://www.example.com, and we have a subdirectory /forum. We want to point http://www.example.com/forum to http://www.anotherexample.com. Is this possible?

Comment: Which web hosting control panel are you using? What kind of server do you have?

Comment: I'm using AWS EC2, my web server is nginx

Answer (score 0):

To handle this via [.htaccess](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^forum/?$ http://www.anotherexample.com [R=301,L,NE]
```

> A 301 redirect is a permanent redirect which passes between 90-99% of
>   link juice (ranking power) to the redirected page. 301 refers to the
>   HTTP status code for this type of redirect. In most instances, the 301
>   redirect is the best method for implementing redirects on a website.

[More About Redirects](https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection)

Alternatively, if you're not comfortable writing RewriteRules, you can use the following line:

```
Redirect 301 /forum/? http://www.anotherexample.com
```

[Common .htaccess Redirects](https://gist.github.com/ScottPhillips/1721489)

Comment: Yes. I've added a resource link for your enlightenment.